# Devise does not allow name attribute - undefined method `name'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I would like to include name in my sign-form using devise.

I therefore
1. Added a name attribute to db/migrate/[timestamp]_devise_create_users.rb

```
t.string :name
```

2. Added an extra div registrations/new view

```
<div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name, autofocus: true, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Enter name" %>
  </div>
```

3. Added the following code to my application_controller allowing devise to take extra attributes:

```
before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

protected

def configure_permitted_parameters
 devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << :name
end
```

But still when I try to open http://localhost:3000/users/sign_up. I get: undefined method `name'

Any clues what goes wrong here?

Comment: Did you edit the migration after it was first run?

Answer (score 0):

Simply Try this

```
 before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?


protected

def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation) }
end
```